# React Native: How to get <TextInput/> to start from right to left?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I would like to get the React Native's `<TextInput/>` input to start from the right and go left. I looked in the docs but couldn't find anything about it.

So how can I get the text input to start from the right side?

Thank you

Comment: provide more code and css

Comment: @AatifBandey ? I looked into the docs but there is nothing about it.. That's why I came here to ask for guidance.

Comment: Can you provide us the CSS you have written for the input field

Answer (score 13, accepted):

did you try textAlign: 'right' ?

Comment: Nope and just did and worked beautifully! Accepted the answer and upvoted

Comment: Just a quick question. In jsx, inline styling, how can you define %? For example, width: '100%' does not work and same for width: 100%.

Comment: there is no % on react native if im not mistaken, instead what i do is get the device width from Dimensions, and let say i want 30% width of the device width. On the style it will be 'width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.3'

Comment: You've been so helpful. Thanks

Comment: That worked but there's another issue on android when the placeholder is overlength. The placeholder will scroll to the end when you touch and swipe it. Still no solution for that.